# How to find the match between text that typo in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have two columns of data with an hundred names on and I need to find the matches.

The problem is when names on the second column are not exactly the same as the first column. Its hard to match them with a hundred names.

Is there any formula in excel for at least give tolerance with the data like "Setyadi" with "Setiadi", or "Tak Jelan" with "Tak Lejan".

---

Thanks for the solution, it works, I edited this because I want to ask more,

I have another problem, could you help me again?
I have a data like this, I want to fill column C with a number according to match the name in column D with column A. The other problem is, I want to match the name that only in a group that mentioned in column E, even not in the same row.

From

```
    A       |  B  |  c  |     D       |  E   |
 Setyadi    |  1  |     |  Setiadi    |  11  |
Tak Jelan   |  2  |     | Tak Lejan   |  11  |
  Gordon    |  3  |     |   Herik     |  12  |
   Alex     |  4  |     |  Goerdon    |  12  |
   Heri     |  5  |     |   Alex      |  12  |
```

Into

```
   A        |  B  |  c  |     D       |  E   |
Setyadi     |  1  |  1  |  Setiadi    |  11  |
Tak Jelan   |  2  |  2  | Tak Lejan   |  11  |
 Gordon     |  3  |  5  |   Herik     |  12  |
  Alex      |  4  |  3  |  Goerdon    |  12  |
  Heri      |  5  |  4  |   Alex      |  12  |
```

What I need is, how can we compare the name in group that mentioned in column D, then We can automatically give the number in column C that coupling from column B.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like John Walkenbach's SOUNDEX() function:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/searching_using_soundex_codes/

Then put the code in Excel:

http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html

Now, if you had this data:

```
A         | B        
Setyadi   | Setiadi  
Tak Jelan | Tak Lejan
```

Now you want to add a formula in C1 like:

`=SOUNDEX(A1)`

And copy that formula to C2, D1, and D2.

Now take a look at your data:

```
A         | B         | SOUNDEX(ColumnA) | SOUNDEX(ColumnB)
Setyadi   | Setiadi   | S330             | S330
Tak Jelan | Tak Lejan | T245             | T242
```

Notice how Setyadi and Setiadi are exactly the same, that's because they **sound** the same, which is why the code from the SOUNDEX function comes back like this.

Now when you look at the Tak Jelan entry, you see that there is a difference of 3 (from T245 to T242). Now, what I would do is creat a new formula where if the first letter is the same, then pull out only the number and compare how close they are like:

`=IF(LEFT(C1,1)=LEFT(D1,1),STDEV.P(MID(C1,2,3),MID(D1,2,3)))`

Then you can compare the std deviation.

Comment: Thanks joseph4tw,
but sorry, I don't know how to use it,
can you give me some help? :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither of the links in this answer work anymore. The VBA code for the SOUNDEX function can be found here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-implementation-of-metaphone-algorithm.252698/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).