# Check if values in 2 different columns contain a match

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have 2 columns in an Excel file (I pulled them from 2 different SQL views on 2 different Servers). That should contain the same data. Example:

```
Name               Name
Adam Smith         Adam Smith
Billy Jones        Bill Jones
Colin Richards     Colin Richards
Dale Cooper        Dal Coop
```

I want to be able to check if each column contains exact matches or partial matches of these names, problem is there is 1000+ names in each column

I have tried VLOOKUP but i don't think I'm doing the logic right. Are their any other ways?

**EDIT**

My VLOOKUP logic i tried was this

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,A:A,1,TRUE)
```

I was trying to match the first value in Column B to match the entire Column of Column A and show as TRUE, that is what i tired

Comment: Share your Vlookup attempts. You can use the `Match` as well. what sheets and columns does your data `Name` sit in ?

Comment: Updated question, i copied the columns into one sheet

Comment: Your vlookup should be fine. Drag that formula down to check all the values in B against column A. Assuming you placed the vlookup in column C, you can then sort column C and have all the #N/A values listed at the top.

Comment: The values dont seem right to me, i believe it is down to the data i am working with. Thank you for your help but feel free to suggest other ways whilst this question is open

Comment: You might have trailing spaces in your data. For example, "John Doe" won't match with "John Doe " with a space at the end. You can use the TRIM() function to fix that.  In cells D1 and E1 enter =TRIM(A1) and =TRIM(B1) and drag those down. Then try doing the vlookup on the two trimmed columns.

Comment: @alfonso thanks for that!

Comment: @Tyeler because both columns dont contain the exact same amount of records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SOUNDEX in sql server. It returns a four-character (SOUNDEX) code to evaluate the similarity of two strings. 
Since you are checking for exact or the partial string match SOUNDEX is a good choice. See soundex documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx. 
I have used soundex for your query and it is giving expected result.

Code as below

```
create table #one(name1 varchar(30),name2 varchar(30))
insert into #one values ('Adam Smith','Adam Smith')
insert into #one values ('Billy Jones','Bill Jones')
insert into #one values ('Colin Richards','Colin Richards')
insert into #one values ('Dale Cooper','Dal Coop')

select *, SOUNDEX(name1) name1_soundex, SOUNDEX(name2) name2_soundex 
from #one where 
SOUNDEX(name1) = SOUNDEX(name2)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pq8v.png)

If you want to use soundex in MS Excel, refer this question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700074/how-to-find-the-match-between-text-that-typo-in-excel
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the columns contain over 1000 lines of data and i cant enter them manually

Comment: Nice answer! I've never heard of SOUNDEX before. I'll be sure to use it int he future. @Nonagon, I don't think you'd have to do this manually.