# Single Column Finding similar values

Tags: sql, excel

I have a column sample data in EXCEL/SQL Table as below.
Want to group similar records. Solution in excel or sql should be fine.

```
GOPAL
Ramesh
A.GOPAL
SRINIVAS
Ramesh Reddy
G.SRINVIASA RAO
```

The expected Output maybe sorting on similarity

```
 GOPAL
 A.GOPAL
 Ramesh
 Ramesh Reddy
 SRINIVAS
 G.SRINVIASA RAO
```

or

```
GOPAL  Group1
A.GOPAL Group1
Ramesh Group2
Ramesh Reddy Group2
SRINIVAS Group3
G.SRINVIASA RAO Group3
```

Comment: What do you mean by group similar records? Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700074/how-to-find-the-match-between-text-that-typo-in-excel  basically sorting by soundex()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment than a complete answer, but may steer you in the right direction.

You will have to define a similarity metric that compares two strings and returns a value that quantifies the similarity between them.  See, for example, [A better similarity ranking algorithm for variable length strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings). How you implement that to use in a SQL query depends on what DBMS you're using.  You will also have to establish a threshold value of this metric that you want to define as 'close enough'.

Then you can write a SQL query something like this:

```
select
    a_val as group,
    b_val as stringval
from
    (
    select
        a_val,
        b_val,
        similarity
    from
        (
        select
            a.stringval as a_val, 
            b.stringval as b_val, 
            sim_metric(a.stringval, b.stringval) as similarity
        from
            stringlist as a,
            stringlist as b
        where
            b.stringval >= a.stringval
        ) as sim
    where
        similarity > similarity_threshold
    ) as grp
order by
    a_val;
```

where `sim_metric()` is your similarity function and `similarity_threshold` is your chosen threshold.  One name in each group of similar names is used as the group name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps. Created a CLR function based on C#code given in the link and it gives me desired results